# Getting a notification when a phone gets paired with a wearable

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a phone app which gets launched on boot and at that point attempts to make a connection to a corresponding app on a wearable device.

However if at that time there isn't a paired wearable then the connection will fail (Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes won't return anything).

Therefore my app will need to re-attempt the connection at a later time. My question there is this: is there something my code can subscribe to to get a callback when the phone gets paired with a wearable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [NodeApi.NodeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.NodeListener.html#onPeerConnected(com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node)) as the method `onPeerConnected(Node peer)`, which looks like what you are looking for. It is invoked when a new peer is reachable from the node, where the callback is invoked